# How do I grant to roles dynamically created permissions?

Tags: 8, users

In my module, I am dynamically creating user permissions for vocabularies. I would like to also grant all roles the view permission, but I cannot figure out a proper way where to do it.

I cannot use a config yml, because these are dynamic permissions created within permission callback and both the hook_install and hook_modules_installed are run before the permission callback, so the roles don't pick up the permissions.

This is how I tried to grant the permissions in `hook_install()` and `hook_modules_installed()`.

```
$vocabularies = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')
  ->loadMultiple();

if (!empty($vocabularies)) {
  foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
    $permission = 'view name defined in the callback ' . $vocabulary->id();
    $anonymous_rid = RoleInterface::ANONYMOUS_ID;
    $authenticated_rid = RoleInterface::AUTHENTICATED_ID;

    if ($anonymous_role = Role::load($anonymous_rid)) {
      $anonymous_role->grantPermission($permission);
    }
    if ($authenticated_role = Role::load($authenticated_rid)) {
      $authenticated_role->grantPermission($permission);
    }
  }
}
```

Where should I grant these permissions within my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After granting the permissions, you should call the `save()` method to make the code work.

```
if ($anonymous_role = Role::load($anonymous_rid)) {
  $anonymous_role->grantPermission($permission);
  $anonymous_role->save();
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I think i even had the save method called once, but it failed for some other reason i guess. But it seems to be a bit unlogical for me that i am able to grant the permissions to a role before they are even created, as both hooks run before the permission callback is called and the permissions are created.